# Tic Tac Toe game implementation using Minimax Algorithm not working python

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, tree, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I implemented Minimax algorithm for tic tac toe.I can't figure out why computer isnt playing a perfect game help me I am new to Data structures.
Your help is appreciated.
All funtions used have been mentioned and their functionality also mentioned

```
'''
My initial List is

_ _ _
_ _ _
_ _ _

functions.py file is imported
var = "X" or "0" (if user chooses X then var is 0 and vice versa as user
can choose that if user wants to play as X or 0)
makemove() --> for computer to make move
functions.main_list --> 2D 3X3 list in which game is being stored
functions.placeinpt(p,var) --> places var(X or 0) at position p
functions.possibleMoves(List) --> This checks possible positions in the list
                                  and returns an array containing possible
                                  positions eg:['1','2','5']
functions.showlist(List) --> Displays the list on the screen
functions.wincases(List,var) --> Check if var (X or 0) is 
                                 winning in the given list
                                 (Check if list contains any
                                 3 in a row winning combination
                                 of variable
    eg: if var = "X" is at (1,2,3) or (4,5,6) position and so on


|1 2 3|
|4 5 6|   # Here 1 2 ...9 are the positions
|7 8 9|

'''

import functions
import math

def makemove(game_state):
    functions.placeInput(minimax(game_state),game_state)

def minimax(game_state): # Returns best move
    if functions.winCases(functions.main_list,"X"):
        return 1
    elif functions.winCases(functions.main_list, "0"):
        return -1
    if functions.possibleMoves(functions.main_list) == []:
        return 0
    moves = functions.possibleMoves(functions.main_list)
    functions.showlist(functions.main_list)
    print("")
    bestscore = - math.inf
    for move in moves:
        clone = functions.placeInput(int(move),game_state)
        score = min_play(game_state)
        if score> bestscore:
            bestmove = int(move)
            bestscore = score

        functions.placeInput(int(move),"_")
    return bestmove


def min_play(game_state): # Returns best score
    if functions.winCases(functions.main_list,"X"):
        return 1
    elif functions.winCases(functions.main_list, "0"):
        return -1
    if functions.possibleMoves(functions.main_list) == []:
        return 0
    moves = functions.possibleMoves(functions.main_list)
    functions.showlist(functions.main_list)
    print("")
    bestscore = math.inf
    for move in moves:
        functions.placeInput(int(move), game_state)
        if game_state == "X":
            game_state = "0"
        else:
            game_state = "X"
        score = max_play(game_state)
        if score < bestscore:
            bestscore = score
            bestmove = move

        functions.placeInput(int(move),"_") # To empty the position when going back up in tree we move so that game state doesnt changes

    return bestscore



def max_play(game_state): # Returns best score
    if functions.winCases(functions.main_list,"X"):
        return 1
    elif functions.winCases(functions.main_list, "0"):
        return -1
    if functions.possibleMoves(functions.main_list) == []:
        return 0
    moves = functions.possibleMoves(functions.main_list)
    functions.showlist(functions.main_list)
    print("")
    bestscore = - math.inf
    for move in moves:
        functions.placeInput(int(move), game_state)
        if game_state == "X":
            game_state = "0"
        else:
            game_state = "X"
        score = min_play(game_state)
        if score > bestscore:
            bestscore = score
            bestmove = move

        functions.placeInput(int(move),"_")

    return bestscore
```

The tutorial I followed [link](http://giocc.com/concise-implementation-of-minimax-through-higher-order-functions.html)
Thank u